# Erro PrestaShop "Cannot select any valid SQL engine. at line 302 in file classes/db/Db.php"

Tags: php, mysql, data, e-commerce

Bom dia,

Tive um problema com os ficheiros do servidor em que foram todos apagados, contudo tinha backup do site todo, posto isto foi efectuado uma reposição de dados, que decorreu na normalidade, mas o que ocorre agora é o seguinte:

```
Cannot select any valid SQL engine.
at line 302 in file classes/db/Db.php

297.         } elseif (extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
298.             $class = 'DbMySQLi';
299.         }
300. 
301.         if (empty($class)) {
302.             throw new PrestaShopException('Cannot select any valid SQL engine.');
303.         }
304. 
305.         return $class;
306.     }
307. 
DbCore::getClass - [line 236 - classes/db/Db.php]
DbCore::getInstance - [line 48 - config/alias.php]
pSQL - [line 340 - classes/shop/Shop.php] - [1 Arguments]
ShopCore::initialize - [line 119 - config/config.inc.php]
require - [line 27 - index.php] - [1 Arguments]
```

Já fiz de tudo, já verifiquei e activei as extensões e nada.

Terei que solicitar ao meu host para fazer um reset e depois fazer o restauro?

É que eu mesmo tentando instalar uma nova loja PrestaShop dá este erro.

Obrigado.

Comment: O erro é o acima citado, mais nenhum.

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando a extensão php mysqlnd.

com o gerenciador de pacotes dnf:
`sudo dnf install php-mysqlnd` (+ reiniciar php) deve resolver o problema.